Why dont I get a file permission for Gem and how can it be solved?
When I try to restore the Gem pristine using the command gem pristine ffi --version 1.16.3, I am getting the following permission error. What is work around for this? I am trying to install cocoapods eventually.
Restoring gems to pristine condition...
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions for the 
    /Users/XXDFDFGDFGDFGXX/.rubies/ruby-3.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/ffi-1.16.3/CHANGELOG.md
    directory.


"I try to restore the Gem pristine" – pristine is the command, the Gem you are restoring is ffi.

Something is wrong with your file permissions in the .rubies folder. You can try to restore the permissions and then try again.
# Restore ownership of everything using sudo
sudo chown -R your_username:your_username /Users/your_username/.rubies

# Set read and write permissions for your user recursively
chmod -R u+rw /Users/your_username/.rubies

Note these are recursive commands, so make sure you type in the path correctly.

The docs suggest to install CocoaPods via sudo using system Ruby (yikes!) which could be the cause for the OP's permission issues.
